# Eclipse Java Editor not recognizing * key

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse, and for some reason it suddenly decided that any time I try to type the * symbol it would instead of showing the * on screen do something like show a little pop up in bottom right corner.  It's not a keyboard thing because if i go out to Notepad, I can type it there and then paste it back into the Java Editor in Eclipse.  Your help fixing this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Look at 'General > Keys' in the Preferences and see if you have anything bound to '*'

Comment: Thanks.  There were some some things that had a binding of Shift + 8.  Funny thing is when I clicked "restore defaults" button those remained.  I mainly removed those bindings.  At first the problem remained, but then i close everything and exited Eclipse and reopened and now * shows up when I type. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some some things that had a binding of Shift + 8. Funny thing is when I clicked "restore defaults" button those remained. I mainly removed those bindings. At first the problem remained, but then i close everything and exited Eclipse and reopened and now * shows up when I type. Thanks. –